# Round up to the next whole number case it contains decimal point (In SQL Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to retrieve a field from a table and display the results rounded up to the next whole number if is not whole yet.

For example:

I have in my table the field working hours.

I need to create de following logic.

```
If working hours/15 equals to 4.01 or whatever grater 4.0 then round to 5
```

Else select as it is (4.0).

Comment: Use the `ceil()` function, which is implemented both in Oracle and in mySQL. The function used to be called "round up" in mathematics; I believe the bad habit of calling it "ceil[ing]" (and similarly "floor" for "round down") is only common in computing circles, not in maths.

Comment: Please add sample and desired data. (not image)

Comment: You taged 2 different databases. Which one is yours?

Comment: @mathguy I'm pretty sure we used floor and ceiling when I did my maths A-levels and degree. Mind you, that was ~25 years ago and parlance may well have changed since then

Comment: @Boneist - I did my maths before you then. Parlance may have changed before you did yours. But I retired from math (going to do other things) only 20 years ago, and - at least in my circles - we never used "ceiling" for "round-up". And, as luck would have it, I had a lot of "round-up" in my very specific area of research, so I know what the terminology was - used by a very large number of mathematicians.

Comment: @mathguy or maybe what I was taught isn’t the usual terminology. “Lies to children” basically describes a lot of what is taught at school, IME! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
with t (n) as (
  select 17.813 from dual
  union all select 20.126 from dual
  union all select 1.000 from dual
  union all select 1.001 from dual
  union all select 1.005 from dual
  union all select 1.009 from dual
  union all select 1.010 from dual
  union all select -1.000 from dual
  union all select 0 from dual
  union all select -1.001 from dual
  union all select -1.005 from dual
  union all select -1.009 from dual
  union all select -1.010 from dual
)
select n, ceil(n) as next_num
from t;

  
N   NEXT_NUM
17.813  18
20.126  21
1   1
1.001   2
1.005   2
1.009   2
1.01    2
-1  -1
0   0
-1.001  -1
-1.005  -1
-1.009  -1
-1.01   -1
```

Comment: Yes, worked for me! Thank you all