# What is the syntax in Oracle to round any number to the next number in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What is the syntax in Oracle to round any number to the next number in Oracle Database even decimal number is less than 5
Eg:-
By using round() function I'm able to get the next number only when the decimal is greater than 5
but I want the next number even though decimal in less than 5

```
value    Exp.Result
1.2      2
1.9      2
2.1      3
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round up to the next whole number case it contains decimal point (In SQL Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69805599/round-up-to-the-next-whole-number-case-it-contains-decimal-point-in-sql-oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `CEIL`ing function to round-up (towards positive infinity).

```sql
SELECT value, CEIL(value)
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 1.2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1.9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2.1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE | CEIL(VALUE) |
| --- | --- |
| 1.2 | 2 |
| 1.9 | 2 |
| 2.1 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Fw7e5d4V)